# Using an Expression with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

So I have the following linq query:

```cs
var query = from s in context.vw_ActiveLabs
            join w in context.Worker on s.WWID equals w.WWID
            join o in context.Org on w.OrgKey equals s.OrgKey
            group ...
```

and I have an `Expression<Func<Org, bool>>` variable that I want to use for the where clause.  I can't figure out how to do that though with this style of linq query.

So ideally I'd do something like:

```cs
Expression<Func<Org, bool>> orgFilter = ...;

var query = from s in context.vw_ActiveLabs
            join w in context.Worker on s.WWID equals w.WWID
            join o in context.Org on w.OrgKey equals s.OrgKey
            where orgFilter(o) == true
            group ...
```

Comment: Well, you *can* use a mixture, to some extent: `from s in vw_ActiveLabs.Where(expression) join ...` would be fine. But it would be harder *after* the join.

Comment: @JonSkeet The expression is on the Org though, not the vw_ActiveLabs.

Comment: It's not clear what you'd *want* it to look like then - it doesn't help that you appear to have `Org` as both the name of a property *and* the name of a type. Providing a [mcve] would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: `Org` is only shown as the table type.  I updated the question to show how I'd ideally use the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe build your query from Org:

```
Expression<Func<Org, bool>> expression = @org => true;
Org.Where(expression.Compile())
      .Include(item => item.Worker)
      .ThenInclude(item => item.vw_ActiveLabs);
```

Comment: I expect that using `expression.Compile()` will force it to execute locally, because it's creating a delegate. Just `Org.Where(expression)` should be fine.

Comment: But Expression type cannnot be used in Where expression, or yes?

Comment: It can for `IQueryable<T>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_Where__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___ Otherwise LINQ for "outside" providers really wouldn't work - half the point of LINQ is to allow the query itself to be done outside .NET, translating the query (including where clauses) into SQL etc.